# How to close previous infowindow when user click on other pin?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im trying to close like this `marker.infowindow.close();` but thats not working. Any suggestion?

```
  marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   noSupress: true,
                   content: ''
                 });
                 marker.addListener('click', (function (marker, i) {

                    return function () {


                        var position = this.position;
                        property_id = locations[i].id;
                        lat = locations[i].lat;
                        lng = locations[i].lng;
                        name = locations[i].name;
                        address = locations[i].address;
                        default_image = locations[i].default_image;
                        $('.hightlight-'+property_id+' a').css('color', '#1996d5');

                        html = '<div class="markerBox">' + '<div class="default_image"><img src="storage/uploads/property' + property_id + "/" + default_image + '" alt="' + name + '"/></div>' + '<div class="content"><h2><a href="/property/' + property_id + '">' + name + '</a></h2><h4><span>Address: </span>' + address + '</h4>' + '</div></div>';
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                        // Reset pin
                        for (var ix = 0; ix < markers.length; ix++) {
                            markers[ix].setIcon(searchPinImage);
                        }
                        map.setZoom(14);
                        marker.setIcon(activePinImage);


                        this.infowindow.setContent(html);
                        //this.infowindow.setPosition(position);
                        this.infowindow.open(map);
                        this.infowindow.setPosition(position);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                            //marker.setIcon(searchPinImage);
                        });
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pGBZD/860/

Comment: can you create a working jsfiddle or snippet , it;s quite difficult to find the issue just in this code , the method is infowindow.close() https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow , it;s possible to have other issues in your code

Comment: @VladuIonut http://jsfiddle.net/pGBZD/860/

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't want to just move the infowindow to the new marker and change its content?

Comment: I have another eventlistner with infowindow ...for example:   markerR.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                 noSupress: true
                               });

Comment: @JaredSmith is that what u ask?

Comment: You should create single infowindow and reuse it as @JaredSmith says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the last open window into a variable ( currentWindow ) and when you try to open other window you can close the last one opened( see the below snippet)

```
 var currentWindow ;
     marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        marker.infowindow.close();
          if (currentWindow) currentWindow.close();
          this.infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
          this.infowindow.open(map, marker);
          currentWindow =  this.infowindow;
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

```js
var locations = [
    [
        "New Mermaid",
        36.9079,
        -76.199,
        1,
        "Georgia Mason",
        "",
        "Norfolk Botanical Gardens, 6700 Azalea Garden Rd.",
        "coming soon"
    ],
    [
        "1950 Fish Dish",
        36.87224,
        -76.29518,
        2,
        "Terry Cox-Joseph",
        "Rowena's",
        "758 W. 22nd Street in front of Rowena's",
        "found"
    ],
    [
        "A Rising Community",
        36.95298,
        -76.25158,
        3,
        "Steven F. Morris",
        "Judy Boone Realty",
        "Norfolk City Library - Pretlow Branch, 9640 Granby St.",
        "found"
    ],
    [
        "A School Of Fish",
        36.88909,
        -76.26055,
        4,
        "Steven F. Morris",
        "Sandfiddler Pawn Shop",
        "5429 Tidewater Dr.",
        "found"
    ],
    [
        "Aubrica the Mermaid (nee: Aubry Alexis)",
        36.8618,
        -76.203,
        5,
        "Myke Irving/ Georgia Mason",
        "USAVE Auto Rental",
        "Virginia Auto Rental on Virginia Beach Blvd",
        "found"
    ]
]

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      // center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8857, -76.2599),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
   marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   noSupress: true,
                   content: ''
                 });
    var currentWindow ;
     marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        marker.infowindow.close();
          if (currentWindow) currentWindow.close();
          this.infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
          this.infowindow.open(map, marker);
          currentWindow =  this.infowindow;
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

```html
  
<div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try change:                    `google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick'`
to 
      `google.maps.event.addListener(this.infowindow, 'closeclick'`

Comment: i want to close previous infowindow when user click on another pin